# RequireJS for Single page application

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application

I am looking for the scope of requirejs for SPA. Can I use it with angularjs?

I got an example for [multipage](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage). But can you tell me an example on SPA?

Comment: angularjs is very suitable for SPA. just use it with angular-router

Comment: Cant I use requirejs in it or ngRoute is enough?

Comment: You can use requirejs, but It's not necessary. You may need the angular's `bootstrap` function to manually bootstrap your app if using requirejs.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be hardcore into AMD using require. But with angular, I usually find it better to just minify my js and use the angular dependency injection. However, there are cases where it makes sense to use angular/require - particularly if you have large chunks of js you only want to load for certain scenarios.

[Here is a good article](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/) to help you understand the basics of angular and require together.